# Using the ITFoxtec library, implementing the switch account functionality with Azure AD and SAML

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am working on an integration with Azure AD, using SAML and the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library. The basic login/logout functionality is working OK.

However, logging into the Azure AD only shows the account selection if the user is already logged into multiple accounts. This seems to be the default behavior, but makes the implementation of "Switch account" functionality difficult.

Currently, the "Switch account" in the application, if the user is logged into one account:

- Performs a logout
- Then redirects back to the login
- The login automatically logs the user in with the single account

The desired behavior:

- Perform a logout
- Redirect back to the login
- The login shows the account selection, even if there is only a single logged in account

What I tried:

- If using OAuth, prompt='select_account' should do the job, but something similar
  doesn't seem to be available.
- The Saml2AuthnRequest class exposes the ForceAuthn property. This
  forces a new login for the user. This could kind off be a
  substitute for "Switch account", but is not ideal.
- In the Azure Portal, I didn't find a setting that may change this
  default behavior.

Is there a way to force the Azure AD login page to show the account selection even if the user is logged into only one account? Or alternatively, to specifically open the Switch account page if that is available?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Azure AD support SAML 2.0 logout. You can instead use OpenID Connect, where Azure AD support logout.

Comment: Unfortunately, using SAML is a requirement for the project.
I don't necessarily need support for Single Signout.
What would be useful is a way to force the account selection screen to always show during login, even if the uses is logged into just only account.

Comment: You can maybe force login by setting the force flag https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L35

Comment: That does work, but only forces the username/password login screen, not the account selection screen. That is however a possible workaround I mentioned above, but isn't what is needed. Thank you in any case.